# How to get the uploaded file link in Jenkins when using publish-over-dropbox plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dropbox-api

I am using jenkins to automate the android build. After the build is successful I am archiving the artifacts and uploading it over dropbox using publish-over-dropbox plugin as a post build action.

Now I want to get the link of the uploaded file after the upload is success. I need the link to send it on slack. Please let me know if you have any solution. Thanks for your help.